# extract lines from F1.sql to F2.sql

Tags: linux

I have a file (f1.sql) with 100's of lines in it. I have to extract all the lines as formatted below from F1.sql and send it into another file say f2.sql

```
ALTER TABLESPACE TEMP ADD TEMPFILE '/dat/ora/dw/temp01.dbf'
     SIZE 65535M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 134217728  MAXSIZE 65535M;
```

key words can be 'ALTER TABLESPACE' for the first line
and 'Next' for the second line.

Comment: Is this reformatted sample correct? If so, are you asking how to extract line "pairs" beginning with ALTER TABLESPACE and containing NEXT on the 2nd line? Are the target lines always paired or could there be multiple SIZE lines OR could the terms be broken up across more than 2 lines? OR is the complete ALTER TABLESPACE command on 1 line? Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `sed` solution:

```
sed -n '/ALTER TABLESPACE/{N;/\n.*NEXT/p}' F1.sql > F2.sql
```

It matches consecutive pairs of lines only.

Demo:

```
$  cat F1.sql 
BLAH

ALTER TABLESPACE TEMP ADD TEMPFILE '/dat/ora/dw/temp01.dbf'
     SIZE 65535M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 134217728  MAXSIZE 65535M;

ALTER TABLESPACE THIS
     ONE WILL NOT MATCH

THIS ONE NEITHER
     ON NEXT WHATEVER

$  sed -n '/ALTER TABLESPACE/{N;/\n.*NEXT/p}' F1.sql 
ALTER TABLESPACE TEMP ADD TEMPFILE '/dat/ora/dw/temp01.dbf'
     SIZE 65535M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 134217728  MAXSIZE 65535M;
```

Comment: Thank you Lev. Worked perfectly.

Comment: @Lincon great! Please consider accepting the answer then (a tick on the left).